# jqgrid sort and paging problem

Tags: jqgrid

I am implementing a jqgrid based on online example. The data is coming up but the sort/page is not working I narrowed down the problem which is: parse error because of special characters (in my case '('  ) in the json.responsetext so I tried to include jquerySpecialCharHandler.js in my page but that did not help. I will include my in here my page and my controller action/function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '/Home/DynamicGridData/',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Policy', 'Policy Rule','Alert Status','Alert Code',
                   'Message','Category'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Policy', index: 'Policy', sortable: true, sorttype: 'text',
              align: 'left', resizable: true },
            { name: 'Policy Rule', index: 'Policy Rule', sortable: true,
              sorttype: 'text', align: 'left', resizable: true },
            { name: 'Alert Status', index: 'AlertStatus', sortable: true,
              align: 'left', resizable: true },
            { name: 'Alert Code', index: 'AlertCode', sortable: true,
              align: 'left', resizable: true },
            { name: 'Message', index: 'Message', sortable: true,
              align: 'left', resizable: true },
            { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', sortable: true,
              align: 'left', resizable: true}],
        pager: $("#pager"),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
        scroll: true,
        sortname: 'Policy',
        sortorder: 'acs',
        autowidth: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
        caption: 'Nebo System Alerts'
    });
});
```

and my function is :

```
public ActionResult DynamicGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows){
    var context = new AlertsManagementDataContext();
    int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;
    int totalRecords = context.Alerts.Count();
    int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
    IQueryable<Alert> alerts = null;
    try
    {
        alerts =  context.Alerts.
                  OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord).
                  Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).
                  Take(pageSize);
    }catch(ParseException ex){
        Response.Write(ex.Position + ex.Message);
    }
    var jsonData = new {
        total = totalPages,
        page = page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = (
            from alert in context.Alerts
            select new {
                id = alert.AlertId,
                cell = new string[] {
                    alert.Policy.Name.ToString(),alert.PolicyRule.ToString(),
                    alert.AlertStatus.Status.ToString(), alert.Code.ToString(),
                    alert.Message.ToString(),alert.Category.Name.ToString()
                }
            }).ToArray()
    };
    return Json(jsonData);
}
```

the exact error message that I recieve during debug is:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException'
>   occurred in Dynamic.DLL Microsoft
>   JScript compilation error: Expected
>   ')'

and the break is highlighting a jquery.jqgrid.js command which is this :

```
addJSONData(eval("("+JSON.responseText+")"),ts.grid.bDiv)
```

needless to say I have gone through several examples but the special characters that I have in my data seems to be the issue and is not being handled, I appreciate any help/advise.

Comment: Which database model you use: LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework? If you use Entity Framework you don't need to use `System.Linq.Dynamic`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found the problem the context.alerts in the json should be alerts, the alerts is the set of data that is being affected by the sort and paging, I thought to put the answer so if someone else faces the same issue might be helpful for them.

Answer (score 0):

Given `System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException` it looks to me like the bug is in the enumeration of `alerts` in your C# code. Try watching those results -- and, in particular, the results of `.ToArray()` during debug. I doubt this is a JavaScript issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have in one of my columns (Message ) some parantheses open and closed, after research i found out that those are special characters that should combined with \\ in the text to be considered part of the text, did you have any encounter with special characters in json.result that returned the datagrid ok and if so can you share that part of your code here, again thanks

Comment: @Sue, I don't think that will cause `System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException`. Your calls into `System.Linq.Dynamic` don't seem to use that column.

Comment: I am new to this so forgive me if this sounds simplistic!  i though the message column was being added in the cell where i select all my columns

Comment: It is being added in that call. But the exception you're getting isn't coming from there. It's coming from `System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException`, as the message says. Try evaluating `alerts` earlier.

Comment: what would I will be watching for in the enumeration special character or a syntax missed?

Comment: one more thing when i create the alert this way                   var alerts =
                      from a in context.Alerts
                      orderby sidx ascending
                      select a;
my data in the data grid comes up but the paging and sorting dont work

Comment: Right. That just confirms what I said. Look at what you're passing to Thte `S.L.D` methods (the LINQ methods which take a string, like the `.OrderBy` overload you're using).

Comment: you are correct looking at the orderby there is no overload that accepts just a string as a parameter and my code alerts = context.Alerts. OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord). Skip(pageIndex * pageSize). Take(pageSize);   tries to put the column and the order by values there that does not look right to me I will research this a bit further any insight you have in this

Comment: does it matter that i have mvc 2 ??

Comment: can you direct me to some examples similar to what I am trying to do ? I searched alot and I find different code bases which requires changing the total approach of my project, it will be really appreciated and save me alot of time

Comment: I have an example on my blog which works. You might want to read the whole series, which discusses this in depth. http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/tag/jqgrid/ For MVC 2, just add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` to the `return Json` line.

Comment: I viewed your link but could not find the example any help ?

Comment: I appreciate your help sincerely, looking at your code I see you utilized the model section of mvc which was not part of the previous example that I followed from http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx page is this because of the js scripts that are different or do you think that example is not complete ?

Comment: I haven't really looked at Phil's demo.